# jQuery Validation with a custom error message which includes a confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, confirmation

I am trying to use the jQuery Validation Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) on a address street field where people have to confirm if their address don't contain a house number (some just forget to write it or whatever).

[image: Form]

So I wrote a custom rule and extended the error message with two buttons like this:

```
// comes from an external file
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    containsnum: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^.*(\d).*$/.test(value);
    }
});
// comes from an external file
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    containsnum: "Does this address have a house number? <button id='yes' class='btn btn-mini'>yes</button> <button id='no' class='btn btn-mini'>no</button>"
});
```

then the actual validation code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xx = $('#customer-data-form').validate({
        debug:true,     

        ignore: ":hidden",
        rules: {
            Anschrift: {
                containsnum:true
            }
        }
    });
    /* check for house number */
    $(document).on('click',"#no",function(e){
        console.log('no')
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#Anschrift').rules( "remove", "containsnum" );
        xx.element('#Anschrift');
    });
    $(document).on('click',"#yes",function(e){
        console.log('yes')  
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#Anschrift').focus();
    });
});
```

It works pretty well but under some circumstances the confirmation (and removal of the rule) just works on the second click on the yes/no button.

I've setup a fiddle with steps to reproduce this behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/CC3zH/2/

The goal is, to make the confirmation of that message work on first click under all circumstances and then I hope for a hint, how to separate the buttons from the Error message string.
I already experimented with errorPlacement etc, but didn't find a simple solution without rewriting all the functions to display the errors.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with how `focusout` and `click` events interact.  If you look around, you'll see that it is a very common issue that `click` events are not triggered correctly when a `focusout` event is also triggered on the element losing focus.  Many solutions are proposed, but one that works in your case is changing your `$.on` handlers to key on `mousedown` instead of `click`, like so:

```
$('#customer-data-form').on('mousedown',"#no",function(e){
    console.log('no')
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#Anschrift').rules( "remove", "containsnum" );
    xx.element('#Anschrift');
});
$('#customer-data-form').on('mousedown',"#yes",function(e){
    console.log('yes')  
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#Anschrift').focus();
});
```

Working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/CC3zH/3/

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to this http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/CC3zH/4/ adding `xx.element('#Anschrift');` to the "yes" button, else it validates all fields.